# How to i change my html5 page into php?

Tags: php, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

if this is my site, index.html. How do i change it into a php file, do i just change from index.html into index.php or do i need to change something before the html tag. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change index.html to index.php. You need to add PHP tags only when you need to execute PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is configured in a default way then changing the extension to `.php` would make the file be parsed by the PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only change it to .php and it will work if you have a standard php server running and configured.

Any modern web site will have the following components:

1. Object Oriented Mechanism.
2. Template System.
3. Object Caching.
4. Browser Caching.

You should read the following resources in order to sharpen your php skills:

http://www.net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/30-php-best-practices-for-beginners/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012315/php-security-best-practices